# shared view items in tab bar controller scene (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I have used the tab bar controller scene provided by xcode.

What I'm trying to do is an application to download copyleft and CC music.

The two tabs will be: "Search" (to search for music) & "Library" (to browse the downloaded music)

Search tab will also give the users, the possibility to stream the music before downloading it.

So, I would like both tabs to use the same player. In android, to do the same it was pretty easy, as it was possible to add the player (button, slider and some label) directly on the parent view and control it though the tabs.

But it seems I have no way to add view directly on the parent view and it seems stupid to create to player to do the same thing.

I am very new to ios (about 4 days...) so I hope there is an easy answer to my question.

I would gladly provide a code with my question but there is no code as it is just the "tabbed application" template from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own UIWindow.
I have used it to add notifications at status bar place

```
UIWindow *notificationWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
notificationWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
notificationWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
notificationWindow.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
notificationWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
notificationWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
```

Comment: As I told you I am very new to xcode, can you explain me where it should be added (wich file) and should I add an element on the sotryboard or ctrl drag something?
Thank you

Comment: I am sorry but I do not think SO is a good place to learn iOS development from zero.

Comment: You should read documentation about UIWindow and UIWindow:windowLevel. Storyboard is not needed here. You can also look at this GitHub repo https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification just for some sample how overlapped window could be implemented.

Comment: Yes I know but I have checked on the net and didn't found any tutorial about my specific case, that's why I ended on SO.